# Насколько программы на java кроссплатформены?

Tags: java

Прогуглил об этом и нашел такую строчку:
"В свою очередь, JVM может быть установлена буквально на любое устройство, что обеспечивает кроссплатформенность Java-программ."

Но разве это так?
Например, для того, чтобы запустить на windows программу, созданную под android, необходимо, как минимум, установить эмулятор. То есть, одной JVM выходит недостаточно.

Это ложь о кроссплатформенности или в этом есть какой-то смысл?

Неужели, чтобы, например, запустить приложение под android на windows phone мне не придется переписывать огромную часть кода?

Comment: Программа под Android — это не только Java, но и привязанность к стандартным Android-библиотекам, которые в комплекте с джавой не идут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Знаете ли, про Си и C++ тоже можно сказать, что они кросс-платформенны и легко компилируются под любую платформу. С одной стороны это правда – на каждой платформе есть компиляторы для них; более того, на большинстве платформ эти языки принципиально важны внутри самой ОС. Однако для реальной разработки кросс-платформенного ПО приходится очень сильно изворачиваться – потому что у разных операционных систем разные библиотеки, ограничения и возможности. В то же время, код основной логики программы зачастую переносится на другие ОС без изменений.

Насчёт приложений под Андроид ситуация немного другая: дело в том, что там используется своя JVM с привязкой именно под ОС Андроида, с её возможностями и ограничениями. Но приложения написанные чисто на Java действительно запускаются где угодно, где есть JVM – эта программа как раз и написана отдельно под разные ОС и минимизирует различия между ними.

Как и с Си/C++, основную логику приложений на чистом Java и на Андроид можно спокойно переносить друг в друга – если не использовать привязанные только к ним библиотеки.

---

**Update.**

Как уже было упомянуто, Java-приложения не нуждаются в перекомпиляции под разные платформы, в то время как C++ нужно компилировать под каждую ОС отдельно, с учётом её фреймворков, библиотек и т.д. Зато используя C++ можно писать почти на любую ОС, как ПК (Windows, Mac OS X, Linux), так и мобильные (Android, iOS), а Java-приложения запускаются только на ПК – конечно, есть ещё Android, но для него приложение здесь нужно сильно дорабатывать, как и в случае с C++.

Если Вас интересует кросс-платформенность в целом, советую почитать про [Xamarin Mono](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono), [Qt](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt), [React Native](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/React), [Unity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA)) (если углубляться в гейм-дев, то ещё [Unreal Engine](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unreal_Engine), [GameMaker:Studio](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GameMaker:_Studio)) – все эти проекты созданы для настоящей кр-платформенности, компиляции под разные ОС с минимумом изменений в коде. При этом, у всех них совершенно разные принципы работы, цены, различные достоинства и недостатки.

Comment: PS: вообще, любая кросс-платформенность либо ограничивает проект тем функционалом, который есть на всех ОС – пропуская те возможности, которые являются уникальными для конкретной ОС. Либо переходит в сложное допилившие проекта под отдельные ОС с их библиотеками и языками программирования – кросс-платформенные инструменты Qt, React Native и другие позволяют легко создавать мобильные приложения под разные ОС из одной кодовой базы, но совсем без фич вроде кастомизации системных всплывающих окон, пуш-уведомлений и других.

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный и развернутый ответ!
А скажите, как по вашему, у Java есть какая-то особенность в плане кроссплатформенности по сравнению с тем же C++, например?

Comment: Особенность в том, что у C++ нет кросс-платформенности.

Comment: Эникейщик, да. Но, получается, что и на C++ можно писать под те же устройства, что и на Java. И переделывать код при переносе приложения на другое устройство примерно одинаково по сложности. Или я не прав? Просто пытаюсь разобраться. Изо всех сил.

Comment: Если вы пишите под C++, то зачем вам java? Если вы пишите под java и используете c++, то перенос делается после перекомпиляции C++ кода, если он будет работать и это уже делается перед инсталляции

Comment: @Yevgeniy, на C++ вы можете писать код для линукс, виндоус, или для холодильника. При этом вы написали программу, собрали её и используете на виндоус, а затем захотели просто взять ту же сборку, скопипастить и использовать на холодильнике. Она у вас там не заработает в общем случае, её нужно пересобрать для холодильника. Java программу не нужно пересобирать, нужно лишь чтобы была установлена виртуальная машина и там, и там. Разумеется есть специфические вещи. А андроид это совершенно отдельная тема, тут не "java программы работают на андроид", а скорее "для андроид пишут на Java".

Comment: Код на С++ нужно компилировать (а скорее всего еще и изменять) под каждую систему. Не получится виндовый экзешник запустить на линуксе. "Скомпилированный" код на яве, если там нет глубоко специфичных вещей, будет работать на любой платформе, где стоит виртуальная машина, без дополнительных манипуляций.

Answer (score 4):

Программы на Java действительно кроссплатформенны, просто у Android своя среда выполнения программ, поэтому без эмулятора Android приложение не запустится. Среда выполнения Android называется Android RunTime (ART), которая пришла на смену Dalvik. Очень интересно описываются эти среды [здесь](http://redroid.ru/art-vs-dalvik-tak-v-chem-zhe-raznitsa/).

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы запустить приложение под Android, нужно его устанавливать на смартфон или планшет. Я не встречал android для персональных компьютеров. Если вы хотите на персоналке запускать приложение под android, то без установки Android вам этого никак не сделать.

Ваше приложение, написанное под Android требует нативного вызова библиотек андроида. Поэтому не является 100% Java совместимым.

О кроссплатформенность можно говорить если ваше приложение 100% java-совместимое. Я не помню, когда-то были сертификациионые центры которые проверяли совместимость вашего java приложения на 100%. Это именно касается платформо-зависимых приложений.